How to use a customized trial wave function in a VQE algorithm?
I'm a beginner in quantum computing, so my question may seem simple. I have a quantum chemistry problem (obtaining ground state energy) in hand that I have already solved it using different standard tools of quantum chemistry such as Variation, HF and DFT methods.
Now I want to solve it using quantum computing tools. Regarding books, resources and papers, I have found the main steps to do a VQE calculation are as follows:

Writing the total Hamiltonian in second quantization space (fermionic Hamiltonian)
Mapping fermionic Hamiltonian to qubit states using Jordan-Wigner or Bravyi-Kitaev transformation.
Creating parametrized ansatz using UCCSD trial wave function
Calculating parametrizing cost function (i.e. expectation value of Hamiltonian) using initial parameters
Optimizing the parametrized cost function and iterating the process until convergence
Post process analysis and error mitigation

This picture is just my understanding, so please correct or complete it, as I'm sure it can be useful for everyone who is a beginner like me.
It's a general VQE picture, but I don't know how can I use my trial wave function in step 3? Because as I mentioned earlier, I have solved my problem using quantum chemistry tools, and specifically using variation method, so I have already a parametrized trial wave function. So how can I use it instead UCCSD one?
Thanks in advance.
